# What is Apple's certificate?

Tags: ios, macos, certificate, public-key, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to understand what the certificate is. I'm talking about the `.cer` file.

In the [description](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/) it sounds like it is a `public key` but if it is, than why do I need Certificate Signing Request (CSR) when creating it?

Everywhere I can find "what is a developer certificate for" and so on, but there is no information what the certificate — as an entity — is.

So my questions are:

1. What is `.cer` file? (Not `.p12`)
2. What is the difference between certificate and [public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The `.cer` is an commonly used extension for certificates. 
Certficates are digitaly signed and encoded documents. To my understanding certificates are documents which contain data (strings etc.) and are encoded. Simply put it is a container for sensitive data.

For details read: [DER vs CRT vs CRM vs PEM](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them)

2) The public key simply put is a value (String for example). This value is stored in a certificate .cer file. 
For better understanding this video might help: [Private and public key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR8ZFRVmQLg)
The difference is that a certificate can contain a public key but a public key cannot contain a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate certify who you are, its a kind of identity card or passport or whatever. A public key is something used to secure something, somehow like a real key closes a safety box not to let everyone have look inside.

Then you may have the need to certify that a public key is the one it claims. A certificate is (normally) obtained from another trusted authority (like your passport is delivered by a legal entity). If not how would you trust a public key I'll give to you? It can be a hacked public key, but if you have a certificate that belongs to it, then (if you trust the authority) you'll know it's really mine and not a forged one.

You may read [Public Key Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) on Wikipedia for example.

`.cer` files are certificates in some well defined format.